# Is there a specific icon format that I should use for Java Swing or Java FX, and if so how do I include it

Tags: java, swing, javafx, icons

I have recently designed an icon in blender for my application. I have exported this as a square 600 by 600 png file. How do I put this in a Java Swing or JavaFX application, and do I need to convert it to a different format? I also need this to be packaged neatly into a .JAR file. The icon needs to display right on all JRE supported platforms. Thank You

Comment: For JavaFX, the [javafx.scene.image.Image](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) class documentation lists the supported formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class is a handy tool for reading and writing images. It supports JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP, and GIF formats. You can also use some third party dependencies like [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) to add support for [more formats](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#file-formats-supported). This is how I would implement it in a Swing application:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");

// Setup frame...

try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myPackage/mySubPackage/myIcon.png")) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    frame.setIconImage(image);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"It supports JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP, and GIF"* That may be the case on Windows, but JPEG, PNG, and GIF are the only formats Java is *guaranteed* to support in the core JRE before support for others are added via the Service Provider Interface. Good call on mentioning `getResource..` for loading application resources, and for implementing it via `try` / `catch`.

Comment: Thank You, I hope that this is helpful to anyone who comes across this post in the future.

Answer (score -1):

`frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Path/To/Your/Image.png")));`
This should add an image to a frame, you can also do a `panel.add()` if you make a new panel and add it to the frame.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be **accessed by URL** rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.